# jQuery - If input has more or less that 10 characters inside

Tags: jquery

I want to make a custom validation for an phone number input.

```
var telVal = $("#telefon").val();
if(telVal == '') {
$("#telefon").addClass('eroare png');
hasError = true;
}
```

This gives me an error if user does not type anything in this input, but I want to check if user types 10 characters. So, the script must be like

> if(telVal has 9 characters or more
>   than 10) { do this }

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So basically, if it's not 10?

```
if(telVal.length != 10)
```

Comment: A question. Would more or less be written as <=10 || >=15 {do this} like PHP?

Comment: @Brad, Yes, but you would need the syntax to be `if(telVal.length <= 10 || telVal.length >= 15)` You have to state the full comparison each time.

Comment: @Florescu — It might be worth only counting numerical characters, so that users can format their phone numbers however they like.  You can do this with `if (telVal.replace(/\D/g, "").length != 10) { ... }`.  That way, both "209-555-1212" and "(209) 555-1212" are considered valid.

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of people have done this before - you can probably find some more advanced parsing samples to include in your solution (such as checking for dashes, parentheses, etc.) on sites like this:

http://www.smartwebby.com/DHTML/phone_no_validation.asp

Comment: Yes, this is good, but I already made my custom jQuery script and it must go the same way like the rest of the script!